# Simulating wireless network transmission

Tags: networking, simulation, wireless

I have an embedded wireless driver for wireless communication that I would like to run in a simulated environment so that I don't have to own hundreds of the devices to test my code.

Ultimately I would like to be able to specify a network connection between nodes, which would be an instance of the C++ code that is used in the embedded device. The connection should simulate the wireless medium such that no packets arrive to the node whilst it is transmitting and no packets arrive at the node if two or more nodes are trying to transmit. Connections modelled by a basic connectivity graph.

I wonder if such a model is possible in the Python Twisted framework. If it is not are there any networking frameworks that would make such a task simple.

Language preferences are Python or Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Network Simulator 2 (NS2). Its a awesome network simulator. Its uses C++ and TCL.